# ASP data exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I was trying to Export data from ASP Classic Application to Excel table by using Do While Loop. During exporting the error(I guess — corrupted date) occurs inside Loop, so the exporting fails and doesn't get to the point where closing tags should be entered.

```
//get data from the database into DataContainer
    Do While Not DataContainer.eof
        response.write "<Row>"
        response.write "<Cell><Data Type=""Number"">" & DataContainer("Field1") & "</Data></Cell>"
        response.write "<Cell><Data Type=""String"">" & DataContainer("Field2") & "</Data></Cell>"
        ... 
        response.write "<Cell><Data Type=""String"">" & DataContainer("Field15") & "</Data></Cell>"
        response.write "</Row>"
        response.flush
        DataContainer.movenext
    Loop
 response.write "</Table>" 
 response.write "</Worksheet>" 
 response.write "</Workbook>"
```

As the result, I have partially exported data into the file. The file can't be opened because of missing closing tags. What are the ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**   Fix the corrupted data so that your loop doesn't fail.

**Option 2.**
Before the loop have the following.  This will cause it to ignore errors and continue.

```
on error resume next
```

Afterwards set it back to normal with

```
on error goto 0
```

e.g.

```
//get data from the database into DataContainer
    on error resume next
    Do While Not DataContainer.eof
        sRow = "<Row>" &_
               "<Cell><Data Type=""Number""></Data></Cell>" &_
               "<Cell><Data Type=""String"">" &_ DataContainer("Field2") & "</Data></Cell>" &_
        ... 
               "<Cell><Data Type=""String"">" &_ DataContainer("Field15") & "</Data></Cell>" 
        If Not Err Then
            response.write sRow
            response.flush
        End If
        DataContainer.movenext
    Loop
    on error goto 0
 response.write "</Table>" 
 response.write "</Worksheet>" 
 response.write "</Workbook>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the matter is that error occurs on the customer's instance where the deployment is rare. 
**1.** Is there any option to catch and fix corrupted data on customer's instance?
**2.** Is there any option to skip row with corrupted data inside the loop and be able to continue exporting next data to the file?

Comment: @OleksandrKulyk  I've updated the answer to show how you might achieve that.